# Need XOR Encryption Algorithm Pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, xor

I am trying to find the pseudocode for the XOR encryption algorithm. However I've had no luck so far. Anybody know where I can find it?

EDIT: XOR 32 if that helps

EDIT 2: For Passwords

Comment: Which xor encryption method?  xor is used in a ton of encryption algorithms.

Comment: @Michael I would assume it is the algorithm where the *whole* encryption is a xor.

Comment: I assumed so as well in my answer, but just checking.

Comment: Same idea - same time.  At least yours is a full function :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean a Vernam cipher, it's just:

```
for i = 0 to length of input
    output[i] = input[i] xor key[i mod key_length]
```

Note that this is quite weak *unless* the key-stream is at least as long as the input, *and* is never re-used.

Comment: Nice for the 32-bit version. I was puzzling over what to do for messages with an uneven length.

Comment: ... in which case it is called "one-time pad" and is the strongest symmetric encryption we have, assuming you know where to get good keys :)

Comment: @Pascal:yes, it's rather an oddity: if you do things just right, it's the strongest cipher around (at least in some ways). If you slip up and do the *least* thing wrong, it degenerates directly from extremely secure to *completely* broken.

Comment: 'quite weak' is a bit of an understatement.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic "xor encryption algorithm" is probably one that just XOR's the plaintext with the key, like so:

```
for each bit of the plaintext:
    ciphertext = bit of plaintext XOR bit of key
```

where the key just wraps around when it reaches the end.

Since XOR is its own inverse, XORing the ciphertext with the key again in the same fashion will reveal the plaintext.

Comment: Yes, though perhaps make it clear that bit x of the input is XORed with bit (x%k) of the key (if it has length k). And it works just as well if you do it per byte rather than bit.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like?

```
unsigned char key = 0x7F;  // or any 8-bit value.
//encrypt

for(int i=0; i < strlen(input); i++)
{
    input[i] ^= key;
}

//decrypt

for(int i=0; i < strlen(input); i++)
{
    input[i] ^= key;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For C:

```
void crypt(char key, char *msg, size_t l)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<l; i++)
  msg[i]^=key;
}

void decrypt(char key, char *msg, size_t l)
{
  crypt(key, msg, l);
}
```